# Why curl -O -C on mac fails to download

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, scripting, osx, wget

The following script works on Ubuntu, but not on Mac. Why? How to edit it so that it would work there too?

```
#!/bin/sh

v=1.1
test_file="Test10.java"
jar_file="dp4j-$v-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

curl -O "http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/dp4j/dp4j/$v/$jar_file"

# Start
cat > $test_file << __EOF__
class T10 {
    private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s){}
}
public class Test10{
    @com.dp4j.InjectReflection
    public void t() {
   T10.p(1,new Double(2),"hello", "reflection");
    }
}
__EOF__
cat $test_file
cmd="javac -Averbose=true -cp $jar_file $test_file"
echo $cmd
$cmd
```

The output on the mac:

```
$ sudo ./TESTDRIVE
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  341k  100  341k    0     0  1516k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3248k
class T10 {
    private static void p(int i, Double d, String... s){}
}
public class Test10{
    @com.dp4j.InjectReflection
    public void t() {
  T10.p(1,new Double(2),"hello", "reflection");
    }
}
javac -Averbose=true -cp dp4j-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar Test10.java
error: error reading dp4j-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar; cannot read zip file
...
```

$ md5 dp4j-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
MD5 (dp4j-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar) = eb04d0d357fd861ac414fde7d3530119

Comment: Try using `curl --fail -O ...` instead.  This will cause `curl` to fail completely if it receives an HTTP error instead of writing the error text to the output file.

Comment: It doesn't fail. 
$ curl --fail -O http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/dp4j/dp4j/1.1/dp4j-1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  341k  100  341k    0     0   576k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  739k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> curl -L

works. It even follows redirects. I found this out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662943/wget-dont-follow-redirects).
Refer to [working script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dp4j/files/1.1/TESTDRIVE/download).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if you're actually getting a .jar file?. Many download links do a silent redirect to where the file actually is, so you might be downloading only a few bytes with a `Location: ...` redirect which CURL isn't following.

Open up the .jar file in a text editor and see what you've got. A real .jar should start with 'PK' (since it's a .zip file).

Comment: tried that..It's not the issue (it works on linux). The jar is indeed downloaded, but corrupt.

Comment: Open the jar in a text editor or `hexdump` it.  For some reason I was receiving an HTML file with a 404 message occasionally under both Windows and on my MacBook.  If the server responds with a 404 status and an error page, then `curl` will gladly write the error page out as a file for you.

Comment: i did all that..it's full of byte code (I already had the problem you guys refer to =) )

Comment: Run it through a zip repairer. See if it's still even remotely a zip file internally. winzip/7zip would do. the CLI zip for Linux has a repair option as well, but I can't remember what the arg is to invoke it.